# Three horizontal stripes in CSS

Tags: html, css, lines

I've created three horizontal stripes to create an extended flag that will run at the top of my page:

CSS

```
#main1 div{
width: auto;
height: 20px;
margin: 0px
```

HTML

```
<div id="main1">
<div style="background-color:red;"></div>
<div style="background-color:blue;"></div>
<div style="background-color:orange;"></div>
```

How to get it to stick right up to the edge of the browser? 
(as in no gaps on the left right or top)

And also is there any easier / better way I could have done this
Keep in mind I'm very much a novice

Your help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: can u show more brief

Comment: what do you mean by show more brief?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove any `margin` and `padding` from `html` and `body` elements, then use a single `div` with a `linear-gradient` as a background

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOxEgJ

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }


#flag {
   height : 100px;
   width  : 100%;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
       red    0%, red  33.33%, 
       blue   0%, blue 66.66%,        
       orange 0%);
}
```