# Multiple background colors with css only

Tags: html, css

I want to have one element with multiple background colors? 
Analog of:

```
<div class="multiplebackground">
  <div style="background-color:red"></div>
  <div style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div style="background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

but if I have only 1 div with some text content:

```
<div class="multiplebackground">
  ...
</div>

.multiplebackground {
  ???
}
```

Or it is not possible?

Comment: Describe what it should look like better. My understanding is that the last color defined would just overwrite the others so... what's the point.

Comment: @alexey Did you mean gradients?

Comment: possibile duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607835/three-horizontal-stripes-in-css ?

Comment: Hey have you tried this below? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081355/how-can-apply-multiple-background-color-to-one-div

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this with gradients. You just need to blend from a colour to the same colour, and then blend to the next colour across zero pixels and so on.

```css
.Neapolitan {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, red 33%, green 33%, green 66%, blue 66%, blue 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Neapolitan">

</div>
```

(Prefixed alternatives and IE specific code is available for older browsers)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.multiplebackground {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, red 33%, green 33%, green 66%, blue 66%, blue 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiplebackground"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

May be linear gradient

> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

```css
body, html {
margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

   #grad {
background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```

Comment: Most of the _modern browers_ do not need the prefixes. Only the standard syntax works fine. [Get rid of prefixes](http://lea.verou.me/2013/04/can-we-get-rid-of-gradient-prefixes/)

Comment: Yes but old browsers is still used too

Comment: Yeah I agree. But the numbers are very less. `-o-` prefixed browers are of 0.25% of the total global user base as stated in the above mentioned article. So are the others. I would prefer this as I want my code to look neat :)

Comment: In Russia Opera was very popular, I think 30% of market few years ago. But after they clone chrome I think popularity is not so big...

Answer (score 2):

Yes...using a linear gradient with color stops

```css
.multiplebackground {
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, red 33%, blue 33%, blue 66%, green 66%);
}
```

```html
<div class="multiplebackground">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the css3 gradient background property!

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, 
            red 33%, 
            green 33%, 
            green 66%, 
            blue 66%);
```

Notice that I define `green` twice, from 33% to 66%. That's because I have to define where it starts  AND where it ends, so i get a sharp edge between every gradient

Answer (score 1):

With CSS you can (as of right now) only style the first row different.

> p:first-line{ background-color: coral;}

if you want something like :nth-line() you have to make it in javascript.

Here is an example of that: http://codepen.io/jnowland/pen/AifjK/

```
var nthLine = function () {
    var content = $('h1').text();
    var words = content.split(" ");
    var cache = words[0]; //because we miss the first word as we need to detect the height.
    var lines = [];
    $("header").append('<h1 id="sample">' + words[0] + '</h1>');
    var size = $('#sample').height();
    var newSize = size;
    for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        var sampleText = $('#sample').html();
        cache = cache + ' ' + words[i];
        marker = [i];
        $('#sample').html(sampleText + ' ' + words[i]);
        var newSize = $('#sample').height();
        if (size !== newSize) {
            cache = cache.substring(0, cache.length - (words[i].length + 1));
            lines.push(cache);
            cache = words[i];
            size = $('#sample').height();
        }
    }
    lines.push(cache);
    cache = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        cache = cache + ' <span class="line-' + [i] + '">' + lines[i] + '</span>'
    }
    $('#sample').remove();
    cache = cache.substring(1);
    //prints the result.
    $('h1').html(cache);
};
nthLine();
$(window).resize(nthLine);
```

Comment: As you can see in the question. I whant to use "css only" and only 1 element.

Comment: @alexey yeah I know, that's why I answered this way. The only way to solve your problem is by splitting up your text in multiple elements.
Using the "linear-gradient" solution will be more complex if you want many colors and then you will style as if all rows were blocks. (you will have background colors where there is no text)